# Getting Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') chartjs

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

Im kind of new to web dev and stuck at a problem when trying to visualize data using a doughnut chart from chartjs.

```
        useEffect(() => {
                const fetchAPI = async() => {
                        const resp = await httpClient.get("//localhost:5000/dashboard")
                        const data = resp.data
                        // console.log("From fetchapi", Object.values(data).map((crypto) => crypto.current))
                        const keys_list = Object.keys(data).map((crypto) => crypto)
                        const data_list = Object.values(data).map((crypto) => crypto.current)

                        //console.log(data_list)

                        setChartData({
                                labels: keys_list,
                                datasets: [
                                        {
                                                label: 'Price in KRW',
                                                data: data_list,
                                        
                                                backgroundColor: [
                                                        "#ffbb11",
                                                        "#ecf0f1",
                                                        "#50AF95"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                ]
                        });


                        
                };
                fetchAPI()
        }, []);

        const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({})


        return(
           <div><Doughnut data = {chartData}</div>
        )
```

`data` here looks like this
`{'eth': {'available': '0.5', 'current': '890'}, 'ada': {'available': '43.9', 'current': '24'}}`

so I'm trying to put data as data.current, here would be ['890', '24'] and the labels as ['eth', 'ada']
However I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') error.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your data is asynchronous. On page load, data is undefined until your data arrives. Add interrogation point like this, which means to make a map if the data exists

```
    useEffect(() => {
                const fetchAPI = async() => {
                        const resp = await httpClient.get("//localhost:5000/dashboard")
                        const data = resp.data
                        // console.log("From fetchapi", Object.values(data).map((crypto) => crypto.current))
                        if(data){
                        const keys_list = Object.keys(data).map((crypto) => crypto)
                        const data_list = Object.values(data).map((crypto) => crypto.current)

                        //console.log(data_list)

                        setChartData({
                                labels: keys_list,
                                datasets: [
                                        {
                                                label: 'Price in KRW',
                                                data: data_list,
                                        
                                                backgroundColor: [
                                                        "#ffbb11",
                                                        "#ecf0f1",
                                                        "#50AF95"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                ]
                        });

                 }

                        
                };
                fetchAPI()
        }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me new information however, I still get the same error:/

Comment: Try again, I just modify the answer

Comment: Still the same :///

Comment: Found the problem!!! add dataset: [] in const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({}) that looks like this const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({datasets: [],})